# How to slide a menu away at a certain time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/6rdzb1x9/

Please see the fiddle above.

1. When user clicks on the work link the first menu slides out.
2. When the user clicks on the Igna link a second menu slides out.
3. When the user clicks on the menu link again both menus slide away.

Question: How do I re-code this so that the first menu slides away only when the second menu has finished sliding back away?

```
 $('#menu').click(function () {
if ($('#fatal').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#fatal').animate({ left: 'toggle' }, 300);
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#igna, #black').slideToggle("slow");
    }, 100);
}

else {
    $('#black, #igna, #igna-1').slideUp("fast");

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#fatal, #igna-2').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300);
    }, 300);
}

});
$('#igna').click(function () {
if ($('#igna-2').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#igna-2').animate({ left: 'show' }, 300);
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#igna-1').slideToggle("slow");
    }, 300);
}

else {
    $('#igna-1').slideToggle("fast");

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#igna-2').animate({ left: 'hide' }, 300);
    }, 300);
}
});
```

Comment: If the second menu is displayed use the `animate()` callback feature to trigger the first menu's hide animation when the second is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment you can use the callback function within `slideToggle()` and `animate()`. This will trigger an event after the animation has been completed. I only modified the `$('#menu')` click event for this and left the rest the same.

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fk7aunw/)

```js
$('#menu').click(function() {
  if ($('#igna-1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('#igna-1').slideToggle("fast", function() {
      $('#igna-2').animate({
        left: 'hide'
      }, 300, function() {
        $('#black, #igna, #igna-1').slideUp("fast", function() {
          $('#fatal, #igna-2').animate({
            left: 'hide'
          }, 300);
        });
      });
    });
  } else if ($('#fatal').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#fatal').animate({
      left: 'toggle'
    }, 300, function() {
      $('#igna, #black').slideToggle("slow");
    });

  } else {
    $('#black, #igna, #igna-1').slideUp("fast", function() {
      $('#fatal, #igna-2').animate({
        left: 'hide'
      }, 300);
    });
  }

});
```